# Error while using xgb.cv

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to use XGBoost to enhance the Accuracy of my model. While I am new to xgboost, I have been trying to understand this algorithm through various sources. I have set the param list with the following code:

```
param = list("objective"="binary:logistic", "eval_metric"="logloss", "eta"=1, "max.depth"=2)
```

and then used:

```
xg.cv = xgb.cv(params=param, data=as.matrix(train), label=train$StatusDesc, 
               nthread=2, nrounds=2, nfold=5)
```

When I run this, I get the below error:

```
 Error in xgb.DMatrix(data, label = label, missing = missing) : 
  [19:55:03] amalgamation/../dmlc-core/src/io/local_filesys.cc:66: 
  LocalFileSystem.GetPathInfo 20160906 Error:No such file or directory.
```

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: Just an FYI, you don't need to quote the names of your list when you define it, `list(objective = "binary:logistic", eval_metric = "logloss", ...)` works just fine and is easier to type.

Comment: Is it required that while using Xgboost, all the categorical variables should be encoded to 0's and 1's?

Comment: Yes. Your training data is a `matrix`, and all data in a matrix has to be the same class. You can't have some factor columns. You should probably start with `xgboost()` and then when you have something working there move to the slightly more complicated `xgb.cv()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. This solved some of my problems.

```
install.packages("drat", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
install.packages("xgboost", repos="http://dmlc.ml/drat/",type="source")
```

Comment: Didn't solve for me. I will try other solutions till then.